# Replacing bullet in begin enumerate with this picture

Tags: beamer, align, enumerate, overleaf

I have already seen other threads regarding this issue, but I am using an alternative approach to do the task. I am able to replace the bullet in the \begin{enumerate} with some pictures, as we will see in the code below. With this thread, I need to know how can I align the pictures better, considering the text?
[image]

As we can see from this picture, the bullet (picture) is not aligned well considering the text. Is it possible to have a more aligned situation?

This is the code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    
    \mode<presentation> {
    
    
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    
    }
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{systeme}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{intcalc}
    \newcommand*{\Myitem}{% 
     \item[{\includegraphics[width=.6cm]{Pic.png}}]\stepcounter{enumi}% 
    } 
    
    
    
    \title[Title]{Title}
    
    \author{Name} % Your name
    \date{\today} 
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
    \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title} 
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}


\section{Section}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{enumerate}
    \Myitem text1
    \Myitem text2
    \Myitem text3
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\raisebox` you can shift your image to align better:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand*{\Myitem}{% 
\item[\raisebox{-1.2mm}{{\includegraphics[width=.6cm]{example-image-a}}}]\stepcounter{enumi}% 
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{enumerate}
    \Myitem text1
    \Myitem text2
    \Myitem text3
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]